# yii : Check if isset Yii::app()->request->getParam('uid')

Tags: yii

This will return 'not set' if in case of uid will, `uid = 0;`

```
if(Yii::app()->request->getParam('uid')){           
   echo "set";
}else{
   echo "not set"; 
}
```

How do I check if 'uid' is set?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @topher : As i have provide short description that i want to apply if(isset()) condition of core php into Yii framework, i just need to check getParam() that uid variable is set or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no method for checking whether a parameter is set. The source code for [`getParam()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#getParam-detail) is as follows:

```
public function getParam($name, $defaultValue=null)
{
    return isset($_GET[$name]) ? $_GET[$name] : (isset($_POST[$name]) ? $_POST[$name] : $defaultValue);
}
```

However, you can implement it yourself:

```
if (isset($_GET['uid']) || isset($_POST['uid'])){           
   echo "set";
} else {
   echo "not set"; 
}
```

Comment: OP's code should work fine though .- `defaultValue` is set to NULL so if it isn't defined, then it's an untruthy value.

Comment: The issue is that if the value is set but falsey e.g zero, the code will fail.

Comment: Ah that makes sense - I didn't understand his question right as an uid of 0 in my book _should_ be equal to "no user".

Comment: Are you sure that, there is no mechanism for to check whether if isset get Params or not ? in yii